# Why the limit of $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ as $x$ approaches 0 is 1?

Tags: calculus, limits

I need a rigorous proof that verify why the limit of $\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}$ as $x$ approaches $0$ is $1$. 
I tried before but i do not know how start this proof.
I would appreciate if somebody help me. Thanks.

Comment: Don't suppose you can use L'Hospital's rule?

Comment: Sure, but i need to know the origin of this theorem, without l'hopital's rule. :)

Comment: So what _can_ you use, if not L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: You could use the Taylor expansion of sin about zero?

Comment: @AlexG.: Using L'Hôpital's rule would be circular. In order to prove that the derivative of $\sin$ is $\cos$, you need to know the limit in the question.

Comment: @msteve What i need is the formal proof of this theorem. But actually i'm a noob making proofs. :( How can i do it with Taylor expansion?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o6S6RbfhRTU

Comment: Read Robjohn's answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1)

Comment: @JohnD I don't understand in the video why there's a point with (1,tan(x))?

Comment: The big triangle is a right triangle, and $\tan\theta={\text{opposite}\over \text{adjacent}}$, but the adjacent side is already 1, making the length of that vertical side $\tan\theta$, which he writes as $\sin\theta\over \cos\theta$.

Comment: You might be interested in looking at the proofs here: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Limit_of_Sine_of_X_over_X

Comment: Note that you need a rigorous definition of $\sin(x)$ before you can hope to have a rigorous proof that $\lim_{x \to 0} \sin(x)/x = 1$.

Comment: @Hurkyl And what can you suggest me for a rigorous definition of sin(x)?

Comment: @egarro: There are a number of approaches that people take. A common one is to take what we know to be the Taylor series for $\sin(x)$ about zero, and *define* $\sin(x)$ to be the value of the Taylor series. A rigorous geometric definition of $\sin(x)$ can be done, but it has a lot of annoying details you have to work through first (e.g. rigorously define things like "arclength" and "angle" and "radian"). Another common one is by its differential equation: $f = \sin$ is the unique solution to $f''(x) = -f(x)$, $f(0) = 0$ and $f'(0)=1$.

Comment: @Hurkyl can you recommend a book for learn more about this topics?

Comment: @egarro One neat way to define the sine and cosine functions is as the solutions to a particular set of [functional equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Definitions_using_functional_equations). Part of the definition requires the sine function to satisfy a certain basic inequality, which you can then apply the squeeze theorem to.

Comment: Plot on the same graph $y=\sin(x)$ and $y=x$ for $0 \leq x \leq 1$. You will see how close the curves are.

Comment: @egarro: I am unable to give a recommendation. Consider looking at some of the more rigorous introductory calculus texts or maybe an advanced calculus text. Or possibly introductory complex analysis texts, as they have to introduce things like $\sin(z)$ for *complex* values of $z$ which is expected to be a novel thing to its audience and requiring careful justification.

Answer (score 12):

Here's a [proof by the squeeze theorem](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-calculus/limits_topic/squeeze_theorem/v/proof--lim--sin-x--x).

Consider a unit circle as in the diagram below.
[image]

The right-angled triangle ABC has hypotenuse 1 because it is a radius of the unit circle. So BC has length $\sin \alpha$.

Similarly, the right-angled triangle ADE has adjacent 1 because it is a radius of the unit circle. So DE has length $\tan \alpha$.

Then the triangle ABE has area $\frac12 b \times h = \frac12 \sin \alpha$. The sector ABE has area $\frac12 \alpha$. And the triangle ADE has area $\frac12 b \times h = \frac12 \tan \alpha$.

And we can clearly see that
$$\frac12 \sin \alpha \lt \frac12 \alpha \lt \frac12 \tan \alpha$$
Dividing by $\frac12 \sin \alpha$ and taking the reciprocals gets us
$$1 \gt \frac{\sin \alpha}{\alpha} \gt \cos \alpha$$
Then, taking the limit as $\alpha \to 0^+$ we have $$1 \ge \lim_{\alpha \to 0^+} \frac{\sin \alpha}{\alpha} \ge 1 \implies \lim_{\alpha \to 0^+} \frac{\sin \alpha}{\alpha} = 1$$
Then setting $\beta = -\alpha$ we get $$\lim_{\beta \to 0^-} \frac{\sin \beta}{\beta} = 1$$
And thus $$\lim_{\alpha \to 0} \frac{\sin \alpha}{\alpha} = 1$$

Comment: Sorry but i didn't get the video's explanation, why there's a side of the triangle named as sin(x), and other as tan(x)? They actually are sides, not trigonometric functions as i know...

Comment: @egarro, the trigonometric functions refer to triangles. If you have a right triangle with appropriate angle $x$ and hypotenuse $1$ then the opposite side will *by definition* be of length $\sin(x)$.

Answer (score 3):

You can expand $ \sin(x) $ using a Taylor series:
$$
        \sin(x)
\approx x - \frac{x^{3}}{3!} + \frac{x^{5}}{5!} - \frac{x^{7}}{7!} + \cdots +
        (-1)^{n} \cdot \frac{x^{2 n + 1}}{(2 n + 1)!}.
$$
Hence,
$$
        \frac{\sin(x)}{x}
\approx 1 - \frac{x^{2}}{3!} + \frac{x^{4}}{5!} - \frac{x^{6}}{7!} + \cdots +
        (-1)^{n} \cdot \frac{x^{2 n}}{(2 n + 1)!}.
$$
Therefore, as $ x $ tends to zero, $ \dfrac{\sin(x)}{x} $ tends to $ 1 $.

Comment: you think that using taylor series it will be right for a formal proof? you know for a test or something like that... ;)

Comment: Disagree with this proof. The individual terms go to $0$, but that does not guarantee that the sum goes to $0$ as well- one has to be careful.

Comment: You can't calculate exact value of sin(x)/x for x=$0$. When you say x tends to $0$, you're already taking an approximation.So, we have to calculate the limit here.Taylor series gives very accurate approximation of sin(x), so it can be used to calculate limit.

Comment: @user3679857 Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: Don't you need derivative of Sinx in Taylor expansion and you need the same limit to find derivative of Sinx?