# Applying Euler's formula for limit of $\frac{\sin(x)}x$ as x approaches $0$ in exponential form

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, complex-numbers

I'm currently studying Euler's formula and the representation of

$\frac{\sin(x)}x$ as $\frac{1}{2ix}(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})$

and my understanding would be taking the limit as $x$ approaches $0$ would be

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0} \frac{1}{2ix}(e^0-e^{-0})$$

which I believe is not right

I think I'm asking two questions:

1. Clarity of Euler's formula (I sort of understanding it from the
   series derivation but in practice I don't understand this at all)
2. Clarity on taking the limit for the real numbers using  this complex representation

Edit: Just wanted to say thank you to everyone who commented, all the answers were very helpful!

Comment: Applying L'Hopital's Rule to $\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2xi}$ gives

$$\dfrac{2ie^{ix}}{2i} = e^{ix}$$

Answer (score 2):

[Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) states that $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+ i\sin(x)$ for any real number $x$, where $ i=\sqrt{-1}$ is the imaginary unit (see [1](https://mathvault.ca/euler-formula/) and [2](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-bc/bc-series-new/bc-10-14/v/euler-s-formula-and-euler-s-identity)). It can obtained from the Maclaurin series expansions of $\cos(x)$, $\sin(x)$ and $e^x$.  Then we have

$$\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2xi}=\frac{\cos(x)+ i\sin(x)-(\cos(-x)+i\sin(-x))}{2xi}=\frac{2i\sin(x)}{2xi}=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$$

since $\cos(x)$ is an even function and $\sin(x)$ is an odd function.

---

It is well know that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=$ [$1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/907362/why-the-limit-of-frac-sinxx-as-x-approaches-0-is-1). If you want to start from the other definition we have

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2ix}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\left(1+ix-\frac{x^2}{2}+...\right)-\left(1-ix-\frac{x^2}{2}+...\right)}{2ix}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{2ix+...}{2ix}=1$$

by power series expansion. You can also use [L'Hopital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule).

Answer (score 1):

We have that by standard limit $\frac{e^x-1}x \to 0$ as $x \to 0$ we obtain

$$\frac{\sin x}x=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2xi}=\frac1{e^{ix}}\frac{e^{2ix}-1}{2ix}\to 1\cdot 1=0$$